# how can i break this loop in android studio

Tags: android, loops, android-studio, break

hi this is the loop how can i break it on that place where i typed I WHANT TO BREAK IT HERE
thanks in advance for the help and i use android studio to develop my app.

```
for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
        if (serverconnection.equals("false")) {
            AsyncHttpPost post = new AsyncHttpPost(serveraddress + "/soton/serveraddress.php");
            post.setTimeout(5000);

            final int finalI = i;
            AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().executeString(post, new AsyncHttpClient.StringCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(final Exception e, AsyncHttpResponse source, final String result) {

                    if (e != null) {
                        MainActivity.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                servernum = finalI+1;
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.activity, "not this IP:"+ servernum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });
                    } else if (result.equals("correct address")) {
                        MainActivity.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.activity,"آدرس جدید پیدا شد",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                serverconnection = "true";
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                                editor.putString("IP", serveraddress+"/");
                                editor.apply();
                                I WHANT TO BREAK IT HERE



                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {


            SharedPreferences.Editor editori = sp.edit();
            editori.putString("IP", serveraddress+"/");
            editori.apply();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop?

Comment: this app connects to a server that i made my self some times the ip of the server changes and i made this code to fetch the new ip and save it to sharedprefrences

Comment: you can't really.  this should be done without a loop, but with a timer/scheduled task

Comment: You can't use a loop. You basically need to wait for the previous call (asynchronous) to return and then, if it fails, try again with i++. Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
else if (result.equals("correct address")) {
                        MainActivity.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.activity,"آدرس جدید پیدا شد",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                serverconnection = "true";
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                                editor.putString("IP", serveraddress+"/");
                                editor.apply();


                         //use break

                         break;

                            }
                        });
```

to break a loop.

> The break command inside the IF statement will exit the FOR loop

Comment: No it won't as the 'for' and 'I WANT TO...' placeholder are not in the same scope

Comment: check my updated answer! this should do the job, did you try it?

Comment: No I haven't (I'm not OP btw). Have you?

Comment: he is asking about breaking the loop, then they should be in same loop inorder for him to break out of it.

Comment: It's not because you have a big pile of code that the instruction are executed sequentially. Here a part is asynchronous. So it's not gonna work (and that's why OP is asking the question)

Answer (score 0):

use a global boolean (AtomicBoolean) variable before the for loop eg. shouldStop. Initially set it's value to false. And check if this value is true on entering the loop. If it's true use break. or just use it as condition in for statement. Now set shouldStop = true in place of I WHANT TO BREAK IT HERE

`//initialize
    AtomicBoolean shouldStop = new AtomicBoolean(Boolean.FALSE);
    //update value
    shouldStop.set(Boolean.TRUE);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
/**
 * Try to connect to the server, with an ip address from 'minIndex' to 'maxIndex';
 * @param context Current Context
 * @param minIndex Index of the ip address to start with. (e.g. 10)
 * @param maxIndex max index
 */
public void testIpConnection(Context context,final int minIndex, final int maxIndex) {
    testConnection(minIndex, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String serverAddress) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "آدرس جدید پیدا شد", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            storeServerAddress(serverAddress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int index, @Nullable Throwable e) {
            if (e != null)
                e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "not this IP:" + index, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            index++;
            if (index < maxIndex)
                // Try again with the same callback and the new index
                testConnection(index, this);
            else
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failure: Max IP reached" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Connect to the server
 *
 * @param index    index to generate the ip
 * @param callback To be call when the request returns.
 */
public void testConnection(final int index, final Callback callback) {
    final String serverAddress = ...; // TODO: Use the index to generate the serverAddress
    AsyncHttpPost post = new AsyncHttpPost(serverAddress + "/soton/serveraddress.php");
    post.setTimeout(5000);

    AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().executeString(post, new AsyncHttpClient.StringCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(final Exception e, AsyncHttpResponse source, final String result) {
            if (result != null && result.equals("correct address")) {
                callback.onSuccess(serverAddress);
            } else {
                callback.onFailure(index, e);
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Store the server address in the SharedPreferences
 *
 * @param serverAddress Address to store
 */
public void storeServerAddress(String serverAddress) {
    SharedPreferences sp = ... // TODO: Define sp here
    SharedPreferences.Editor editori = sp.edit();
    editori.putString("IP", serverAddress + "/");
    editori.apply();
}

/**
 * To be call when on a result of a server call
 */
private interface Callback {
    void onSuccess(String serverAddress);

    void onFailure(int index, Throwable e);
}
```

Comment: Basically, it tries with index `i`, then if it fails, it tries again with `i + 1`, until `max`